# Disable password toggle ImageButton when TextInputEditText is disabled

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

When a TextInputLayout's `app:passwordToggleEnabled` attribute is set to true and a TextInputEditText's `android:enabled` attribute is set to false, how can one prevent the password toggle ImageButton from being clickable?

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="24dp"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLength="32"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:enabled="false"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: Issue demo]

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should `setEnabled` of the TextInputLayout to `false` rather than the `TextInputEditText `

Comment: Crap. This was an oversight on my part. I had previously tried setting enabled via an xml attribute on TextInputLayout only to realize that it doesn't exist. I unfortunately did not then go back and check if there was a Java setter. Thank you for your help, your comment has resolved my issue.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, a simple solution to your problem would be to setEnabled of the `TextInputLayout` to false rather than the `TextInputEditText`. Since the `TextInputLayout` houses the `TextInputEditText`, the entire layout would be disabled by this. Here's a little demo:

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);

if(someCondition){
    textInputLayout.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!